# Before Update Event Conundrum Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

Alright I have some interesting interactions going on and I want some advice from my seasoned VBA cats to help me see if there is a way more elegant way to approach my situation.

Details:

1. Have a check box on a Form. This check box is Bound to a table.
2. Have a combo box on a subform on the original form.
3. On the beforeupdate event on the main form, there is data validation that checks if Checkbox =True then combobox cannot be null. This is intended to keep the user from switching records without performing needed updated.

So the issue is, I need to be able to enforce the data integrity as well as not hinder UI flow as much as possible. It's worth noting that in the beforeupdate event I cannot use Cancel = True because when you try to switch focus to the subform the beforeupdate event fires, which obviously this creates an INF lock in UI Flow. Another issue is once the update event fires, the checkbox value gets written to a table. Unchecking the checkbox ends up creating another loop of sorts.

My solution so far:

in the before update event

```
If Checkbox = True and IsNull(Me!ComboBox) = True Then
    lastRecord = Me.CurrentRecord
    chkBool = True
end if
```

in the Form_Current Event

```
currRecord = Me.CurrentRecord

If currRecord <> lastRecord And chkBool = True Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "form", acGoTo, lastRecord
    GoTo Exit_Form_Current
ElseIf currRecord = lastRecord And chkBool = True Then
    'do stuff
    vbSql = "Update Statement"
    DoCmd.RunSQL vbSql
    chkBool = False
    Me.Refresh
End If
```

Is there a better way to approach this? Or is the wonky work around kind of how i have to approach it?  Sadly I cant redesign to circumvent it due to the subform needing to be a continuous subform.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check for *Null* correctly:

```
If Me!Checkbox = True And IsNull(Me!ComboBox) Then
    lastRecord = Me.CurrentRecord
    chkBool = True
End If
```

Then evaluate how this works together with the second piece of code.

Comment: Well i did I just posted psuedo code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

you say "On the beforeupdate event on the main form, there is data validation that checks if Checkbox =True then combobox cannot be null." one approach would be to not wait until the beforeupdate event on the main form; do a check as soon as the checkbox is checked. if the combobox is null, don't allow the check to happen; force the user into the subform first. that might bring up other issues but...